# javascript hide test/pictures

Tags: javascript, html

I use this to hide my answers from the flashcards. However, when I start up the webpage all the answers are showing and I have to manually hide them. HOw do I get everything hidden when I startup or open up the webpage.
I need the answers hidden

```
  function myShowText(id) {
   document.querySelector('#' + id + ' .answer').style.color = 'black';
}

function myHideText(id) {
  document.querySelector('#' + id + ' .answer').style.color = 'white';
}
.answer {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #287EC7;
  color: white;
}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Flashcards VBA </title>
  <rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
 </head>

<body>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <h3> Flashcards </h3>
  <p class="question">
    The first question
  </p>

  <div id="bash_start">
    <p class="answer">
      <img src="image.jpg">
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `display: none` in the css.

```
.answer {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #287EC7;
  color: white;
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: does not work  - when I start the page all the answers show.

Comment: give display: none !important;

Answer (score 0):

Hide the answer on `window.onload`

```
 window.onload=function(){
document.querySelector('.answer').style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```js
window.onload=function(){
document.querySelector('.answer').style.visibility = "hidden";
}
function myShowText(id) {
   document.querySelector('#' + id + ' .answer').style.color = 'black';
}

function myHideText(id) {
  document.querySelector('#' + id + ' .answer').style.color = 'white';
}
```

```css
.answer {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #287EC7;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">


<body>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <h3> Flashcards </h3>
  <p class="question">
    The first question
  </p>

  <div id="bash_start">
    <p class="answer">
      <img src="image.jpg">
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code. hideAnswers() should be called on page start script. Then you can display answers using showAnswers()

```
function hideAnswers(){
var answers = document.getElementsByClassName("answer");
  var answer;
  for(var i = 0; i <= answers.length-1; i++){
   answer = answers[i];
   answer.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}

function showAnswers(){
var answers = document.getElementsByClassName("answer");
  var answer;
  for(var i = 0; i <= answers.length-1; i++){
   answer = answers[i];
   answer.style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
```